# IPSec AES 256 encryption in Windows XP with Service Pack 3?

Tags: windows-xp, aes, ipsec

Does IPsec in Windows XP Sp3 support AES-256 encryption?

**Update:**

1. Windows IPsec FAQ says that it's not supported in Windows XP, but maybe they changed it in Service Pack 3?

   http://www.microsoft.com/technet/network/ipsec/ipsecfaq.mspx

   Question: *Is Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) encryption supported?*
2. origamigumby, please specify where, because I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Windows XP SP3.
When I add a new IPsec filter rule, the only options for ESP I get are DES and 3DES, so the FAQ is correct - there is no support for AES prior to Windows Vista.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT*** http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd125380.aspx indicates that my original link (https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://search.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/search/microsoft+windows+and+network+security.html) was wrong.

It is not supported prior to Vista.